# Open database of whole slide digital pathology images

Tags: pathology, database

I am looking for sequential image sections (stacks) of biological structures (such as liver, kidneys etc.) that I can download and use. Most of the pathology images I have found are either one image or 3-4 sections. I am looking for >50 sections to test some code.

Is there a public repository for this kind of data?

Comment: you could try the new Google tool https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch - it's searching for open scientific data. You might also find something here: https://github.com/sfikas/medical-imaging-datasets

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately i could not find any stacks or sections in the sites you recommended. I am looking for series of images (stacks or sections), it seems that those are not widely available.